What's the deal with ん゙?
Why does ん゙ exist and what sound does it even make?

Also this counts for any other sound with Dakuten (other than か, さ, た, は, & オ)

Any examples and context?  I may as well ask why ⟨ ₽ ⟩ exists, or ⟨ ł ⟩ or ⟨ ṅ ⟩ or ...  With examples and context, much becomes clear.

Also: Why is there dakuten on the "ん" in this image? / Dakuten on る character

In short, if ん is like "mm", ん゛ is like "MMMGH!".

@naruto How would you pronounce ん゙ out loud? Louder version of ん, or what?

@Arfrever Not necessarily loud. A person who has a cold or is weeping may say ま゛だね゛, which is like "Zee you doborrow".
